# Dependency Injection best practices in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, dependency-injection

In Symfony2 (2.8 in this case) what is considered best practice when injecting services into another service?

```
/**
 * Checker constructor.
 * @param EntityManager $em
 * @param EventDispatcherInterface $dispatcher
 */
public function __construct(EntityManager $em, EventDispatcherInterface $dispatcher)
{
    $this->repoUser = $em->getRepository(User::class);
    $this->repoPurchase = $em->getRepository(Purchase::class);
    $this->repoTicket = $em->getRepository(Ticket::class);
    $this->dispatcher = $dispatcher;
}
```

or

```
/**
 * Checker constructor.
 * @param UserRepository $ur
 * @param PurchaseRepository $pr
 * @param TicketRepository $tr
 * @param EventDispatcherInterface $dispatcher
 */
public function __construct(UserRepository $ur, PurchaseRepository $pr, TicketRepository $tr, EventDispatcherInterface $dispatcher)
{
    $this->repoUser = $ur;
    $this->repoPurchase = $pr;
    $this->repoTicket = $tr;
    $this->dispatcher = $dispatcher;
}
```

or use setters explicitly and set arguments to them individually in `services.yml`?

I wonder what's the performance part of the equation as well.

Comment: You're **probably** best off with the 1st one, reason being 1) more flexibility if you need other repositories later aswell (or cut some), since you only need to touch that class and not the `services.yml` (this one is debateable, but **I** think it's cleaner) 2) The ServiceContainer only needs to look up one reference, instead of several.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are pros and cons in both cases.

- In terms of **performance**, both options are equal, because you get instances of repositories only when you request instance of your service. Doesn't matter you do it manually, or it's done automatically by DI. As mentined [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html),

  > The container is lazy: it doesn't instantiate a service until (and unless) you ask for it.
- If you are going to cover your service with **Unit tests** - then option 2 is definatelly better, because you don't need to mock $em->getRepository() calls in the beginning of the test.
- Benefits of **individual setters** - is also related to unit testing. For example, for one test case you need only one dependency, for another test case - another dependency. So, you can use setters inside of test to set mocks, and you don't need to pass all mocks into constructor.

Comment: I don't think it's a huge deal with mocks - you can always disable the constructor altogether, and mocking 3-4 dependencies on a class is usually pretty simple.  But that's just my opinion :)

Comment: Look closely at the posted code.  The repos are pulled from the entity manager as soon as the service is constructed.  No performance differences at all.  Your third point about unit tests and individual settings is really stretching things.  Either the class needs it's dependencies or it doesn't.  If a class only needs some dependencies some of the time then it should probably be refactored.

Comment: Indeed, in one case you pull repositories manually, in another DI do it for you, but also only at the moment service is requested. Answer updated, thanks for pointing.